# Three.js lightMap causes an error WebGLRenderingContext: GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm loading a jpeg file for light map 
`var texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("textures/metal.jpg");`
Then I apply the texture to THREE.MeshPhongMaterial

```
var frontMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
         color: 0xfade7e,
         specular: 0xffffff,
         ambient: 0xaa0000,
         lightMap:texture
    } )
```

Full error message is `WebGLRenderingContext: GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 2`

Is here something wrong? An error occures in all browsers. Three.js r.56

Comment: This is a guess so I won't put it as an answer.. Try using also a normal diffuse texture map. I vaguely remember some other features bugging when material only has a color, but no texture.

Comment: @yaku `MeshPhongMaterial` does in fact work properly with a light map and no diffuse texture map. r.56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by @alteredq in [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/2372) thread, a `LightMap` requires a second set of UVs.

> The point of lightmaps is that they can live independently of other textures, thus giving other textures chance to be much higher detail. Lightmaps use their own set of UV coordinates (usually auto-generated by some light baking solution, as opposed to artist-created primary UV set).
>
> Using lightmaps with the same UVs as everything else doesn't make much sense, as then you could achieve basically the same result for less texture cost simply by baking light map together with color map (this is e.g. what Rage uses, it looks fantastic but needs boatload of textures).
>
> Also lightmaps should be multiplicative, not additive. Big use case for lightmaps are pre-baked shadows and ambient occlusion, so you need to be able to darken things.

So the answer to your question is that `geometry.faceVertexUvs[0]` contains the usual set of UVs; you need to add to your geometry `geometry.faceVertexUvs[1]`.

three.js r.56

Answer (score 0):

This error become because the Three.js buffers are outdated. When your add some textures (map,bumpMap ...) to a Mesh, you must recompose the buffers and update UVs like this :

```
ob is  THREE.Mesh, mt is a Material, tex is a texture.

tex.needsUpdate = true;
mt.map = tex;
ob.material = mt;
ob.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true;
ob.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
mt.needsUpdate = true;
```

That's all folks !

Hope it's help.

Regards.

Sayris