# Strange bump map and not working light map with Three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to use a temporary space ship model within my `Three.js` based project. This model have color, bump, specular and light maps.

So, my problems are:

- The bump map seens strange/wrong. You can check the result [here](http://luizdepra.com.br/test/swdnpiv/).
  Ship grooves seems too deep, and on the bottom side of the ship the grooves are too bright.

What I'm doing wrong? I'm creating the object using `SceneLoader`, loading the `.obj` file and textures. Here are some snippets of the JSON file.

**Object:**

```
"ship" : {
    "type": "obj",
    "url" : "res/object/ship/space_frigate_6.obj",
    "material": "ship",
    "position": [0, 0, 0],
    "rotation": [0, 4.71, 0],
    "scale": [0.08, 0.08, 0.08],
    "visible": true
}
```

**Material:**

```
"ship": {
    "type": "MeshPhongMaterial",
    "parameters": {
        "map": "ship_color",
        "bumpMap": "ship_bump",
        "specularMap": "ship_specular",
        "bumpMap": "ship_bump",
        "bumpScale": 1
    }
}
```

**Textures:**

```
"ship_color": {
    "url": "res/texture/ship/space_frigate_6_color.jpg",
    "anisotropy": 4
},

"ship_bump": {
    "url": "res/texture/ship/space_frigate_6_bump.jpg",
    "anisotropy": 4
},

"ship_specular": {
    "url": "res/texture/ship/space_frigate_6_specular.jpg",
    "anisotropy": 4
}
```

This is a problem with the texture or I'm doing something wrong?

- Light map wont work:

I loaded the light map texture in the same way of the another ones, and added it to the material. I got a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`, but ok, I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137695/three-js-lightmap-causes-an-error-webglrenderingcontext-gl-error-gl-invalid-op). I tryed it, putting this in the code ´obj.children[0].geometry.faceVertexUvs[1] = obj.children[0].geometry.faceVertexUvs[0]´,  but no success. Got just a black ship on the screen.

What I need to do to light map work?

You can check my project on [GitHub](https://github.com/RawArkanis/swdnpiv):

- [Scene JSON](https://github.com/RawArkanis/swdnpiv/blob/master/www/js/game/scene/test.json)
- [Game Scene Class](https://github.com/RawArkanis/swdnpiv/blob/master/www/js/game/scene/game_scene.js)
- [Ship Class](https://github.com/RawArkanis/swdnpiv/blob/master/www/js/game/entity/ship.js)
- [OBJ Folder](https://github.com/RawArkanis/swdnpiv/tree/master/www/res/object/ship)
- [Texture Folder](https://github.com/RawArkanis/swdnpiv/tree/master/www/res/texture/ship)

Tahnk you.

Comment: Please have only one topic or problem per post. If you have multiple issues, create separate posts for each of them.  As to the bump map issue, have you tried adjusting the `bumpScale`? Try lower values such as 0.1

Comment: @yaku worked! Seems `bumpScale` need to be the same value of the mesh scale, right?